# Amazon Glue, Python library requirement files version update causes failure in AWS Glue Jobs

Tags: python-3.x, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

Python library requirement files version update causes failure in AWS Glue Jobs.
causes random package errors like this

> error: Could not find suitable distribution for
> Requirement.parse('pandas==1.1.5')

How to lock the version for particular version, any future updates should not throw error in glue jobs.
Any solution to this?

Comment: as far as i know, `pandas v1.0.1` is included in glue2.0 by default. Alternatively you could download pandas1.1.5 whl file and upload it to s3 and load it from there with `--additional-python-modules s3://<bucket-name>/<file>`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html#aws-glue-programming-python-libraries-zipping

Comment: Thanks For the comment @Bijay Regmi . I'm looking into this.